# angularjs ng-model binding with data from array.

Tags: angularjs

I am having quite a problem.I have a form.The input fields are populated with datas from server.But the array key in the data dont match the input field.
Here initial data from server:

```
info={
    "code":"COD-12",
    "notes":"some random notes",
    "settigs":[{
    "field_code":"FCOD-112",
    "field_name":"somme name",
    "field_name":"12"
   }]
 }


  dataSave={
   "name":"john",
   "works":{
     "work_code":"COD-12",
     "notes":"some random notes",
     "all_settigs":[{
       "code":"FCOD-112",
       "name":"somme name",
       "name":"12"
      }] 
     }
  }
```

The input fields related to settings need to be populated. Since,the key name in the two json are different I am having difficulty binding these value with each other.
I tried ng-init in input field`<input ng-init="dataSave.works.work_code=info.code" ng-model="dataSave.works.work_code">
Any help would be helpful.`

Comment: Nothing is understood. Pls explain properly.

Comment: @Peterson I want to bind the value of first json data into the form so that I can use to save by editing some of it.